# Indefinite integral of rational functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

This question seemed very trivial at the first glance, but evidently it is a non-trivial problem, at least, for me.

Let $p, q$ be polynomials in $x$, and $\deg q > \deg p$, with $q (x)$ being irreducible, and there is no constant $A$ such that $q ' (x) = A p (x)$. Then how do we find $$I (x) = \int \frac {p (x)} {q (x)} dx?$$ I cannot even calculate the integral for individual pairs of $(p (x), q (x))$, let alone for the general case.

I tried decomposing the given fraction to such parts whose anti-derivatives are known, but it became more complicated than the original problem. Then I tried integrating by parts, which resulted in terribly tedious and far more complicated integrals. I tried using expansions, i.e., for some function $y (x) \in (-1, 1)$ I tried differentiating, integrating or doing some other operations several times the expression $$\frac {1} {1 - y} = \sum y^k$$ to arrive at $p (x) / q (x)$, but all to no avail.

I think either I'm stupid or I'm unaware of a theory regarding this, or there's indeed no method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no formula involving $p$ and $q$ that works in the general case. However, every rational function can indeed be integrated exactly. Check out [this link](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~rbrown/courses/ma114.f.03/lec13.pdf), it's a great summary

Comment: @MPV Thank you for the link. I read up the lecture. Nothing new. Doesn't answer my question. What if, say, I want to find the anti-derivative of $$\frac {x^3 + 2x^2 - 4x + 5} {x^5 - 4}?$$ Can you please inform me more? Maybe as an answer regarding this exampe...

Comment: in $\Bbb C$ there are no such polynomials $p$ and $q$, as every polynomial is reducible to linear factors. Solve it in $\Bbb C$, You will get non-real component results, but with the right integration constant, the total function will carry real arguments to real values.

Comment: @Paul So, you say I decompose the fraction, since $q (x)$ will be reducible on complex field. Thank you. Please, elaborate it and put it in an answer, so that I can accept it.